# How to add dynamic content after reading the xlsx file and before saving it to database?

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer, xlsx

I want to import student results from xlsx file and save those to couchdb.
I am using Node JS.My xlsx files contains following columns.

```
student_id,student_name,student_email,marks,total_marks,percentages
```

before saving to database I want to assign rank to every students based on their percentages.

How can I achieve this with Node JS?

Answer (score 0):

when u import xlsx file result will be array of object
like:

```
result=[
        { student_id:"123",student_name:"abc",percentage="10"},
        { student_id:"321",student_name:"def",percentage="36"}
       ]
```

so you can add key student_rank on every object before saving to database
like:

```
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
       if(percentage=="60")
         result[i].student_rank="First"
  }
```